# Signature of doc file in C#

Tags: ms-office

Actually I am a consultant and prepares standardized documents. So what I need is
that set the signatures of a msword file and let in intact i.e. no one can edit the signatures and forward it to somebody else.
Is it possible ? If yes then how

Comment: How far are you in your own research? Have you figured anything out already?

Comment: This is not a question about programming. This is a generic question about MS Word features. Word already supports signing through its Security options. Information Rights Management is also provided to prevent unauthorised users from opening a document, although it requires the proper certificates and infrastructure. Please start by reading Word's help and documentation, eg at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/protect-a-document-from-unauthorized-changes-HP001044674.aspx

Comment: well I can incorporate encryption to protect the document but once the document is with my client along with the key to open the document then he/she can do anytype of modification.

Comment: What about if put barcode or watermark sign in the document itself. In that case if the client edit the signature too then also my proprietorship will be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Signing proves authorship (or approval) of the document by the owner of the signature. Signature can not be used to prevent distribution of the document, neither it can prevent third-parties editing documents. One can edit document data - this would invalidate the signature but unsigned document can be derived from a signed one with some modifications anyway.

Encryption can prevent modifications and disclosure of data, yet the person who has the key can do anything with the document after its decrypted.

Our SecureBlackbox product lets you sign and encrypt MS Office documents if you need, yet you need to clearly define what you need to accomplish and how signing and encryption can (or can't) help you with your goals.

Comment: Thats the crux. I have to give the document to my client for viewing/editing etc but want to get it secured also in a way once I specify my signature the those cant be edited anymore

Comment: @Nitin editing will invalidate your signature so you can give a signed document for viewing. But the client can just copy file contents to a new document and you can't do anything about this - it's a digital world.